# Error after execution of this script?

Tags: php, sql

I get an error on the 4th line of this code. This doesn't make sense to me. It worked yesterday and now it doesn't.

Here is the error message that I get after I include this:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in /PATH/classes/users.php on line 5`

```
<?php

class Users {

    public static function load($where = NULL, $order = 'name', $bind = NULL) {
        global $db;

        $sql = 'SELECT cspsp_accounts.*, cspsp_clans.id AS clan_id, cspsp_clans.name AS clan_name, cspsp_clans.tag AS clan_tag ' .
               'FROM cspsp_accounts ' .
               'LEFT JOIN cspsp_clanlinks ON cspsp_accounts.id=cspsp_clanlinks.account_id AND cspsp_clanlinks.active=1 AND cspsp_clanlinks.approved=1 ' .
               'LEFT JOIN cspsp_clans ON cspsp_clans.id=cspsp_clanlinks.clan_id ' .
               'WHERE (cspsp_accounts.id=cspsp_clanlinks.account_id OR cspsp_clanlinks.account_id IS NULL) ' . (($where) ? ('AND (' . $where . ') ') : ('')) .
               'ORDER BY ' . $order;

        $rows = $db->run($sql, $bind);

        if(is_array($rows)) {
            $users = array();
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $users[] = new User($row);
            }

            return $users;
        }

        return false;
    }

}

?>
```

Here is the full code: http://codepad.org/1qS7iwTv
Thank you all in advanced!

Comment: `public static function load(..` gives me an error.

Comment: I have just copy/pasted your code and it's working fine. Is that your whole PHP file?

Comment: Sorry for deviating from the question. I could not help noticing that developers are using inline sql statement quite a lot. I have gone through several questions where this is done. I am not sure if they are considering SQL Injection attack as a big issue.

Comment: http://codepad.org/1iYusrkF

Comment: Check if the where condition your are passing is having correct syntax.

Comment: http://cspsp.tk/ I am getting this error.

Comment: @user2342080 Which PHP version do you use? I can see `PHP/5.3.24` in your server's response headers. Is this right?

Comment: @ARS SQL injection is only an issue when you can't trust the variables you are using in your sql query. Aslong as $order and $where are hardcoded somewhere else in the code and not coming from user input, , there is no problem.

Comment: There's no way I could get attacked because those variables never contain user input.

Comment: Here is the full code - http://codepad.org/1qS7iwTv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have some bad white-space issues,
I corrected the line #5 by retyping the 4 spaces  <kbd>Space</kbd>   before `public static function load`.. which pushed the error to line 6.

See here http://codepad.org/egWvMgPd

After copying it into sublime2 and copying it back i get a working version

http://codepad.org/Fi3zWNvk

Comment: How exact did you fix it?

Comment: I retyped the white-space, your editor/keyboard language combination might be causing some illegal characters to be entered

Comment: What language is your computer system defaulting to?

Comment: I coded that on my iPod, English.

Comment: If that error keeps occurring, I suggest not coding on iPod \o_O/

Comment: It just started to happen. I had to restore my website and stuff, but it's a simple coding mistake. Thank you guys,  you just saved me hours.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29799/discussion-between-moak-and-user2342080)